# How to fill an entity type choice field with brand new element generated by the prototype in Symfony Form?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, symfony

I have a situation like this:

I have a main Form(Entity "Races") which has a Collection(Entity "Racial Traits") embedded to it.

In this collection, there is a field called "Replacing" which is self-referencing with his own Entity ("Racial Traits"), holding a Many to Many relation.
This field is used to determine IF the current racial trait will replace one or more other Racial Traits and WHICH ones.

All work fine in a normal behaviour:

- Adding new traits trigger the prototype correctly, the relations Races - Racial Traits and such is fine
- The EntityType load correctly already persisted instance from the Db

What i want to achieve is to force populate ALL the current EntityType Fields the user is creating via the prototyping ("Add a new Racial Trait") with the new racial traits he is precisely inserting.

for istance if an user would add two new racial traits he will have, for each "Replacing Field" (the EntityType)

> -Trait A (retrived from the Db)
>
> -Trait B (retrived from the Db)
>
> -New Trait (via "Add new Racial Trait")
>
> -New Trait 2 (via "Add new Racial Trait")

I've already tried to use javascript/jquery to manipolate the field themself but offcourse this prompetd an error into the validation, because i've no idea how to bind my new value to the EntityType.
I wanted to now if there is a best practice to achieve something like this which im obviously forgotting.

No code to show at the moment, because the problem lies into the logic itself which I'm afraid of having misapplied.

thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue in a wacky way, and it's good as long i dont find a better soluton:

Scenario:

- As soon as new item collection are added, i want to populate my entityfield with brand new added item.
- The ending result, will be something like:

  [Form

  [[Collection 1

  [[[EntityField: Collection 1, Collection 2, Collection 3

  [[Collection 2

  [[[EntityField: Collection 1, Collection 2, Collection 3

  [[Collection 3

  [[[EntityField: Collection 1, Collection 2, Collection 3

i tryed different approach on the matter:

First i tryed using only FormEvent, modifying my Entity field with the choices inserted into the viewData via Jquery.
Problem was that using `PRE_SUBMIT` or `SUBMIT`, both let me operate only with a single collection item, resolving the event in this way:

PRE_SUBMIT Collection 1 -> SUBMIT Collection 1 -> PRE_SUBMIT Collection 2 -> SUBMIT Collection 2 -> PRE_SUBMIT Collection 2 -> SUBMIT Collection 2 -> PRE_SUBMIT Form 1 -> SUBMIT Form 1

This meant i cannot read the information of Collection 2 from Collection 1 event, because they were not set into the normal/model View already, and viceversa operating from Collection 2/3/or N, meant that my previous collection were already submitted.

so the best solution was to:

- Change my entityField in a unmapped ChoiceField via a PRE_SET_DATA event only for the "newAction"
- set a list (array) of the possible choices created by the user into an Unmapped Hidden Field, populated in the same way i did with my brand new unmapped ChoiceField
- Into the PRE_SUBMIT, updating the choices of my unmpped ChoiceField with the content of the Hidden field.
- then, from the controller, use that unmapped ChoiceField to sets my Self Referencing Relationship.

And well, it works. Hope this can help others with the same needs.
Obviusly if someone has a better suggestion, im glaad to ear!